# Make Vertes,TexCoords,Norms and Indices vuforia

Tags: android, vuforia

I use of Vuforia sdk for AR in android.
I make 3d file with jpct(obj file,mtl file and png file),i add these file on my project,how can i make my object 3d object file(like teapot class) for set Vertes,TexCoords,Norms and Indices in vuforia.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I mean,how can i replace teapot 3d obj file in Vuforia?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with vuforia, per se.

Qualcomm uses a simple renderer for their demos, for convenience and so they can have something to display.  There are many possible ways to render an obj file, but there is nothing special about their approach.  I do not recommend using that approach in your code:  rather, a quick search will show you a variety of much more capable 3d model loader/renderers for android.  You should use one of those, it will be better for you in the long run.

If you you are dead-set on using their code, look at the code that renders the teapot, it should be obvious how the data in the teapot class is used.

Comment: thanks,can you tell me,how can i add my 3d obj file...?

Comment: Have you looked at how it is used in the program?  The arrays in the Teapot.h file are the arrays (vertex, textureCoordintates, Normals, triangle indices) that are handed directly to the OpenGL rendering commands.  You need to MANUALLY create the corresponding set of arrays for your file.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Blaiir Maclntyre,how can i create manually? is there wizard way?

Comment: It's a text file:  any text editor will do.  The obj file format is well documented (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) and the format in the Teapot file is pretty clear (again:  look where those arrays are used, and look at the documentation for those function).  but, again:  I think you are wasting your time.  If you do not want to do this manually, google around for an obj loader/renderer and use it (e.g., the first hit in google for me is https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader, which is one.  There are hundreds).